# Jboss migration application issues

Tags: jboss, migration, java-11

iam doing migrating from jdk 8 to 11 and jboss 6.4 to 7.4 ,

after migrating standalone.xml,getting below deployment errors.can anyone help with solutions
[stderr] (Finalizer) javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|03|Finalizer|2023-09-01 16:46:42.165 MST|SSLSocketImpl.java:578|duplex close of SSLSocket

ERROR [stderr] (Finalizer) javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|03|Finalizer|2023-09-01 16:46:42.262 MST|SSLSocketImpl.java:1756|close the SSL connection (passive)

[org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."ROOT.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."ROOT.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "ROOT.war"

ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "ROOT.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit."ROOT.war".POST_MODULE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "ROOT.war"

can any one provide the sample xml file or any dependency i need to  add